GCP Workflow: unable to pass input parameter to for loop
I have a workflow like this:
main:
  params: [input]
  steps:
    - assign_vars:
        assign:
          - my_list: ${default(map.get(input, "my_list"), [])}
    - for_each_item:
        parallel:
          for:
            value: item
            in: my_list
            steps:
              - log_item:
                  call: sys.log
                  args:
                    data: item

The assumption is that when executing the workflow, I will supply an input like this:
{ "my_list": ["foo", "bar"] }

However, when I try to deploy the workflow an error message is shown:
Could not deploy workflow: failed to build: error in step for_each_item: for-in loop is allowed only for an array object (Code: 3)

Is passing runtime arguments to a for loop not supported? I was not able to find this information in the documentation.

I realized I need to wrap my list variable in the workflow like this
in: ${my_list}

